# Cognitive logistic regression modelling in R

Tags: r, data-modeling, logistic-regression

I am trying to build a Logistic Regression model that is able to run regardless of the nature of the predictor variables as long as the response variable stays the same. Here's a sample of what I have in mind:

```
#Take in the data
newdata = read.csv("book1.csv", head = TRUE) 

#Store the response variable whose column heading you know beforehand
y = "response.variable"

#Identify the predictor variables (this is where I am stuck)
#Below is the algorithm of what I have in mind though 
1) Take remaining column headings except "response.variable"
2) Store them as x = c(other headings)

#Form of model
model.form = reformulate(x, response = y)

#Build model
logit = glm(model.form, family = "binomial", data = newdata)
```

Any ideas are welcome.

Edit:
When I use the code 
    glm(y ~., data = newdata) 
as suggested by @laterow, it gives an error statement:

```
 Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]:
 contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

Comment: `glm(y ~ ., data = newdata)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your predictor variables are all of the remaining variables in your data.frame, use the following to select them:

```
x <- names(newdata)[-which(names(newdata) == "response.variable")]
```

The `names()` function returns the names of all variables in a data.frame. The super helpful `which()` function returns the index of the elements in a vector that match some conditional expression.

Comment: Thanks @Imo. this worked very well for what I had in mind.